# CSS background-image: repeating-linear-gradient cross browser

Tags: css

The following CSS class is only working in modern chorme or firefox:

```
.grating{
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
        transparent, 
        transparent 7px, 
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 5px, 
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 10px
    );
}
```

So I need some CSS code that will work in old IE too. I think I need something like this:

```
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF);
```

And for IE should be:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0);
/*IE8+*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0)";
```

These are just examples for other CSS classes not for mine.

Ultimately what I need is this:

[image: pic]

(just the white stripes) background-color can be different in different situations and sqaure size can be bigger or smaller, so I just need stripes that should be one transparent antoher white, one transparent antoher white....

I have no idea how to traduce my class to IE <10 friendly syntaxes...I think I need some expert help...

Comment: You can use this tool to achieve what you want - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Define "Old IE"....basically, repeating linear gradients just won't work in 'old IE' versions AFAIK

Comment: Next to [Colorzilla gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) there is also the [CSSmatic Gradient CSS Generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'\-moz\-linear\-gradient\%28left\%2C\%20rgba\%28248\%2C80\%2C50\%2C1\%29\%200\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28241\%2C111\%2C92\%2C1\%29\%2050\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28246\%2C41\%2C12\%2C1\%29\%2051\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28240\%2C47\%2C23\%2C1\%29\%2071\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28231\%2C56\%2C39\%2C1\%29\%20100\%25\%29\%3B')

Comment: In both tools they don't seem to accept my code when I try to import it... @Luis P.A.

Comment: Only when I delete the transparent part imports it and I need it to be transparent..

Comment: I am not able to get the exact same thing that i need in those tools starting a new config in the tools, as importing my css is not working...

Comment: You can create transparent in this tools...Just replicate what you want.

Comment: @ Luis P.A. And how do I replicate in the tool to repeat the gradient (string) every 7px? I can't find an option for that

Comment: So...show us an image of you gradient...I will help you to reproduce it. (do you want to achieve  a gradient or a pattern? If is pattern you should use this tool -http://www.stripegenerator.com/

Comment: @Luis P.A. I've been 40 minutes playing around and I cant get what I need..I edited my explanation adding what I need exactly.. I registered In your last website but after creating stripe i can share the website but i cant get the code...

Answer (score 2):

Browser Support
The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property.

Numbers followed by -webkit-, -moz-, or -o- specify the first version that worked with a prefix.

> repeating-linear-gradient

---

> - IE      >   10.0
> - chrome  >   26.0   -webkit- (10.0)
> - firefox >   16.0   -moz-   (3.6)
> - safari  >   6.1    -webkit- (5.1)
> - opera   >   12.1    -o- (11.1)

### [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient), [support browser (caniuse)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients)

```
.grating {
  /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
  /* Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
  /* Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
  /* Standard syntax */
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
 /* IE 5 to 9*/
 filter:
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=13, direction=310)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Wheel(duration=3);
 }
```

Comment: My question is how the part of "filter" (por IE (5 to 9) should be to do exactly what i want... i tried many different things but i can't get it working in IE5 to IE9